# float left не работает

Tags: html, float

Сижу учусь, моя первая верстка (очень криво)
Надо поставить картинки в ряд и задать им width: 48% и float: left чтобы отражались в ряд по 2 каритнки и маштабировались при изменении размера окна. Если задавать размер в %, то отражаются друг под другом, а если в px, то все ок, но с маштабом окна все плохо.

```css
.row:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.row { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .row { height: 1%; }
.row { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
.c-text {
 float: left;
 font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 position: initial;

}

.content {
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
}

.site img{
 width: 47%;
 margin: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #5c5c5c inset, 0 0 10px 0px #20201e;
 transition: 1s;
 transform: none;

}

.site:hover img{
 margin: 5px;
 transform: scale(1.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #5c5c5c inset, 0 0 70px 0px #20201e;

}

.site {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="content">
  <div class="c-text">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">ТЕСТ</h1>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так потому-что у тебя картинки лежат в `.site`, вот ему давай `width: 48%`, а картинки уже растягивай на весь этот блок. Или ещё проще, убери блок `.site` и всё заработает

Comment: спасибо :) вроде работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо у элементов с классом .site добавить `width: 47%` и убрать `float: left`. Эти элементы, согласно CSS имеют `display: inline-block`, это делает их блочно строчными, которые и так будут располагаться друг за другом как строчные, например `input`, или `img`.

Картинкам `.site img` изменить `width: 100%`.

```css
.row:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.row { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .row { height: 1%; }
.row { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
.c-text {
 float: left;
 font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 position: initial;

}

.content {
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
}

.site img{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #5c5c5c inset, 0 0 10px 0px #20201e;
 transition: 1s;
 transform: none;

}

.site:hover img{
 margin: 5px;
 transform: scale(1.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0 #5c5c5c inset, 0 0 70px 0px #20201e;

}

.site {
    width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="content">
  <div class="c-text">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">ТЕСТ</h1>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="site">
     <img src="http://wallpapers-image.ru/1600x900/summer/wallpapers/wallpapers-summer-067.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```